# Overriding Dead Letter Queue Bootstrap Servers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

While opening a connector, we can override the bootstrap servers by giving this line:
`"producer.override.bootstrap.servers": "http://cluster2_server1:9072,http://cluster2_server2:9072"`

Lets say by default I'm creating all my connectors to read/write data on cluster1. Above way I can make them work with topics on cluster2. But when a DLQ is needed, it will be created on default cluster (cluster1in this case).

Is there a way to create DLQs on the same cluster as overridden one? Checked the documentation but couldn't find anything about it.